# Necesito Pintar un array de objects en un option de un Select

Tags: java, jquery

Necesito que con la libreria jquery y la herramienta .append mediante un bucle foreach me aparezcan en un option de un select el nombre del objecto, tengo un array de objectos :

[Object [id=1, atributo2=ejemplo], Object [id=2, atributo2=ejemplo2]] tengo este array y yo quiero que con la opción .append me aparezca en un option de un select mediante jquery y utilizando la etiqueta del id del select. Un saludo

Comment: Has probado algo? Por favor comparte siempre tus avances cuando tengas este tipo de problema, para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: si, probé esto pero me dice que forEach is not a function : function Objecto(id, nombre){
    this.id = id,
    this.nombre = nombre
   }
   
   
   array.forEach(function(Objecto){
    $("#ejemplo").append(`<option>${Objecto.id}</option>`);
   });

Answer (score 0):

Mi Array de Objectos es este: [Color [id=1, codigoOColor=Rojo], Color [id=2, codigoOColor=Verde]]
y este es mi código jquery para recorrer ese array y pintarlo en un option:
            function Color(id, codigoOColor){
                this.id = id,
                this.codigoOColor = codigoOColor
            }

```
        function mostrarColores(){
            $.each(colores, function(color){

                let html = `<option>${color.id}</option>`;

                $("#ejemploColor").append(html);
            }); 
        }

        mostrarColores();
```

- Cuando lo ejecuto me dice lo siguiente:
  Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in [Color [id=1, codigoOColor=Rojo], Color [id=2, codigoOColor=Verde]]

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que en tu controller o servlet en java establezcas una lista como el siguiente

```
ArrayList miLista = new ArrayList();
...
request.setAttribute("miLista", miLista);
```

y ya despues de eso en tu jsp lo recorres de esta manera con un foreach, sin necesidad de usar JQuery

```
<select name="database1">
  <c:forEach items="${lista}" var="miLista">
    <option value="${lista}">
        ${lista}
    </option>
  </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Saludos

Comment: El problema es que es de varios productos, no es de uno solo, yo tengo una lista de productos y cuando pulso en un botón me coge el id de ese producto y a través de su id recojo la lista de colores de ese producto, y a la hora de mostrarlo en un select necesito traer primero su id y entonces coger su lista de colores, pero necesito recorrer ese array con jquery pero me daba ese error, al ser un array de objects. ¿Sabrías alguna forma de recorrer dicho array con jquery?

Comment: Comparte tu codigo, para que entender mejor lo que tratas de solucionar bro,